# Where do I find Javasript SDK to connect a device to AWS IIoT Greengrass?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a Raspberry Pi (let's call it "A") which has  Greengrass Core running on it. Additionally I have another Raspberry Pi (let's call it "B") which has sensors. Data of sensors from Raspberry Pi "B" needs to be sent to the AWS Greengrass on Raspberry Pi "A".

I know that there is a Python SDK available for this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/greengrass/latest/developerguide/IoT-SDK.html) - but I want to use Node.JS to develop the part on Raspberry Pi "B", and did not have success so far looking for a Javascript SDK for that scenario.

Any suggestions on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please make sure you read the help docs about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking/). Asking for pointers/recommendations to libraries are normally considered off topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of availalbe Greengrass SDKs in the AWS documentation in [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/lambda-functions.html).

```
Language or platform    GGC version
Python 2.7              1.0 or later
Python 3.7              1.9
Java 8                  1.1 or later
Node.js 6.10            1.1 or later
Node.js 8.10            1.9
C, C++                  1.6 or later
```

The Node.JS SDK is referenced [here on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-greengrass-core-sdk-js/).